# ViewPager + fragment stack

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, kotlin

1. Есть активность -> добавляется фрагмент A методом replace
2. У этого фрагмента A есть view pager -> соответственно два фрагмента добавляются используя child fragment manager
3. Далее я из фрагмента A перехожу в фрагмент B (добавляю в стек)
4. В фрагмент B я добавляю дочерний фрагмент (пусть бует C)
5. У фрагмента C также есть вью пейджер в которых 2 фрагмента - также юзаю child fragment manager.

Проблема: мне нужно из фрагмента C вернуться на A. Когда я это делаю, то фрагмент A инициализируется(все методы жизненого цикла отрабатывают), но не показывается.
В чем может быть проблема?

код инициализации адаптера во фрагменте A:

```
    private fun initViewPager() {
    tabLayout?.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    val sectionsPagerAdapter = MyChatsPagerAdapter(
        childFragmentManager,
        context!!,
        arrayOf(MyChatsPagerAdapter.TabItem.CHATS, MyChatsPagerAdapter.TabItem.RECOMMENDATIONS)
    )
    viewPager?.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
}
```

Код перехода из А в Б

```
     fun showChatScreen(chatId: String, chatName: String) {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("chatId", chatId)
    bundle.putSerializable("chatName", chatName)
    val mainChatFragment = MainChatFragment()
    mainChatFragment.arguments = bundle
    val ft = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
    ft?.replace(R.id.container, mainChatFragment, "chatScreen")?.addToBackStack("chatScreen")
        ?.commit()
}
```

Код перехода из Б в С

```
    private fun showChat() {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("chatId", idChat)
    bundle.putBoolean("fromMap", fromMap)
    bundle.putString("stateChat", stateChat)
    val chatFragment = ChatFragment()
    chatFragment.arguments = bundle
    val ft = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.mainContainer, chatFragment).commit()
}
```

Переход из С в А ->

```
(parentFragment as? MainChatFragment)?.myCustomBack()
```

где myCustomBack - метод в фрагмента A:

```
 fun myCustomBack () {
        fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104137/discussion-on-question-by-tony-viewpager-fragment-stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в Progress Bar который был в фрагментмене view pager`a фрагмента C
Как только я убрал методы видимости этого прогресс бара. Проблемы ушли.

Answer (score -1):

"Проблема" заключается в том, что вы используете `replace` для навигации по фрагментам. Как следует из названия, он заменяет один фрагмент на другой, в следствие чего фрагменты, которые заменяют, уничтожаются. Чтобы этого не происходило, используете метод `add`.

Comment: Когда я делаю replace фрагмента A на B, то фрагмент B добавляется в стек
Соответсвенно он должен восстановиться заново при переходе назад